# Error on my Linked List code, can anybody help me to check where is wrong?

Tags: c++, linked-list

Here is a small Linked List challenge from my class that we need to define a function

```
void restoreSorted(intListEntry * &)
```

where intListEntry is a struct

```
struct intListEntry {
    int i;   // The int value we want to store in this entry
    intListEntry *next;   // Address of the next entry in the list
};
```

The argument is the head of a linked list of integers that sorted in non-decreasing order except for one entry, which is out of place. The function should restore the list to sorted non-decreasing. For example, given as argument; head --> -12 --> -12 --> 0 --> -1 --> 12 --> 122, up on return from restoreSorted(), the list should be: head --> -12 --> -12 --> -1 --> 0 --> 12 --> 122.

and here is my code:

```
void restoreSorted(intListEntry * &root) {
    intListEntry *conductor = root;
    intListEntry *checker;

    while (conductor->next != NULL) {
        if (conductor->i > conductor->next->i) {    //detect which one is out of place
            checker = conductor;
            intListEntry *checker2 = conductor->next;
            int temp;
            while (checker->i > checker2->i) {
                temp = checker->i;            //start of swapping value 
                checker->i = checker2->i;     //until it is in the right order
                checker2->i = temp;
                checker = checker2;
                checker2 = checker2->next;
            }
            break;
        }
        conductor = conductor->next;
    }
```

However, there are five test cases, and I only pass one of them. I check it over and over again I still cannot find any bug in my code.

Comment: But I see that the result list is not sorted. Could you elaborate this?

Comment: if root is NULL, your code would segfault. BTW, why not using STL list?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to just re-adjust the links than changing the values?

Comment: The `break` will exit the `while`. Btw, `checker2 = checker2->next;` might make `checker2` null when it reaches the end of the list. Also, you're not really sorting the list items, but only changing member values of list items. Typically with linked lists, you remove an item from the list and insert it somewhere else - maybe this will be expected by your teacher?

Comment: Do you mean my code does not sort the given list or the result list in my question provided is not sorted ? If it is regarding my question, I think I put the correct result list. If it is regarding of my code, this is where I am struggling with right now. I can't find any bug.

Comment: Ok, thank you for all of your answer, I see what wrong with my checker2. And thanks for giving the insertion method, but I honestly I prefer swapping, even though it is more tedious.

Comment: @LeonMa If I was you professor, you would not receive full credits for swapping the `int`s. That's the whole point of using linked lists, to swap only the pointers, less times.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of the those comments, I finally debug my code and make two versions using different approach.

The first one is using my original method - bubble sort:

```
void restoreSorted( intListEntry * &root ){
    int length = 0;
    intListEntry *current = root;
    intListEntry *prev = NULL;
    int t = 0;
    while (current != NULL){
        length++;
        prev = current;
        current = current -> next;
    }
    current = root;
    prev = NULL;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < length-1 ; j++){
            if (prev == NULL){
                prev = current;
                current = current->next;
            }
            if (current->i < prev->i){
                t = prev->i;
                prev->i = current->i;
                current->i = t;
                current = current->next;  
            } else {
                prev = current;
                current = current->next;
            }
            if (current == NULL) break; 
        }
        current = root;
        prev = NULL;
    }
}
```

The second one is using insertion method:

```
void restoreSorted(intListEntry * &root) {
    intListEntry *conductor = root;
    intListEntry *behind = root;
    intListEntry *checker;

    if (conductor != NULL || conductor->next != NULL) {
        while (conductor->next != NULL) {
            if (conductor->i > conductor->next->i) {
                checker = conductor;
                intListEntry *checker2 = conductor;

                if (checker2->next->next == NULL) {
                    int temp = checker->i;
                    checker->i = checker2->next->i;
                    checker2->next->i = temp;
                    break;
                } else {
                    while (checker->i > checker2->next->i && checker2->next != NULL) {
                        checker2 = checker2->next;
                    }
                    if (checker->i > checker2->i && checker2->next == NULL) {
                        behind->next = checker->next;
                        checker2->next = checker;
                        checker->next = NULL;
                    } else if (checker->i < checker2->next->i) {
                        behind->next = checker->next;
                        conductor = checker2->next;
                        checker2->next = checker;
                        checker->next = conductor;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            behind = conductor;
            conductor = conductor->next;
        }
    }
}
```